# Integrating the Fourier series term-by-term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> The function $\phi(x) = x$ on the interval $[-l,l]$ has the Fourier series
>   $$x = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{l} \right) + \frac{1}{3}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l} \right) - \ldots \right)$$b.) Integrate the series term-by-term to find the Fourier series for $\frac{1}{2}x^2$, up tp a constant of integration (which is then the $\frac{1}{2}A_0$ term in the cosine series). Find the $A_0$ using the standard formula to completely determine the series.

Understanding - I am not sure if I understand what we are asked here to do. I believe we need to compute $$\int_{0}^{l} \frac{2 l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) dx$$
but I am not sure, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{l} \frac{2 l}{\pi} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) dx$$

Comment: Looks nasty, know any of the details of integrating this horrendous thing?

Comment: Note that $\frac{2 l}{\pi} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}$ is independent of $x$, so you can move those factors out of the integral.